# How many subsets of size 4 are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[image]

All I can think of is there are $2^8$ subsets of the set. Then, there are $2^5$ subsets of size $5.$ So $2^8-2^5$ gives you the number of subsets of four elements. How do I even approach this problem?

Comment: There aren't $2^5$ subsets of size $5$...there are $\binom 85$.  And why would the number of subsets of size $5$ plus the number of size $4$ equal the total number of subsets?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Make a grid where the rows are labeled one to eight, and the columns are labeled with the subsets. Place a check mark in a box if the subset at that column contains the number at that row. Then every row has three check marks, and every column has four...

Comment: Do you mention $70$ columns ...

Comment: No, there is only a column for each subset being considered. @user376343

Comment: I was thinking of 4-element subsets, total number. Because at the beginning we don't know the convenient collection of subsets.